# New record after a year of no records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to find returning customers who have placed an order after a year without orders. I have managed the below but am having a tough time adding the year gap. Something like "and count of orders between dates = 0"... any ideas would be appreciated, I cant seem to figure out the required syntax at all.

```
SELECT
  Min(Orders.[Order Date]) AS [MinOfOrder Date],
  Max(Orders.[Order Date]) AS [MaxOfOrder Date],
  Orders.CustomerID
FROM
  Customers
  INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY
  Orders.CustomerID
HAVING
  (
    ((Min(Orders.[Order Date])) < Date() -365)
    AND ((Max(Orders.[Order Date])) > Date() -30)
  );
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of your `Orders` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` and `not exists` to get the first order after a year gap:

```
select o.*
from orders as o
where exists (select 1
              from orders as o2
              where o2.customerid = o.customerid and
                    o2.orderdate < dateadd("yyyy", o.orderdate, -1)
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from orders as o2
                  where o2.customerid = o.customerid and
                        o2.orderdate >= dateadd("yyyy", o.orderdate, -1) and
                        o2.orderdate < o.orderdate
                 );
```

You can join in the customers information if you need that.

Comment: Beauty, the dateadd function needed to be adjusted but really nice thank you.

Comment: @royca . . . I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting records based on values in other records is tricky. Use a correlated subquery to pull value from another record. Need a unique identifier field - autonumber should serve. Consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT Orders.*, (SELECT Max(OrderDate) 
                  FROM Orders AS Dupe 
                  WHERE Dupe.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
                  AND Dupe.ID < Orders.ID) AS PrevOrderDate
FROM Orders;
```

Query2:
`SELECT Query1.* FROM Query1 WHERE ((([OrderDate]-[PrevOrderDate])>365));`

Comment: Thank you, I will remember querying a query is an option.